# i try to make a profile screen like instagram but i got an error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 99719 pixels on the right."

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8spw.png)

i try to use singlescrollview or flexible. it doesn't work. i use expanded but it still render like that. the circular image profile and username bellow not able to see. its look fine at the start but suddenly become a render, i don't have a clue about this. maybe there is some mistake in my code?

here is the code
`

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instagram/resources/auth_methods.dart';
import 'package:instagram/resources/firestore_methods.dart';
import 'package:instagram/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:instagram/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:instagram/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:instagram/widgets/follow_button.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;
  const ProfileScreen({super.key, required this.uid});

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  var userData = {};
  int postLen = 0;
  int followers = 0;
  int following = 0;
  bool isFollowing = false;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      var userSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(widget.uid)
          .get();
      //get post length
      var postSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .get();
      postLen = postSnap.docs.length;
      userData = userSnap.data()!;
      followers = userSnap.data()!['followers'].length;
      following = userSnap.data()!['following'].length;
      isFollowing = userSnap
          .data()!['followers']
          .contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      var snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString()));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
              title: Text(
                userData['username'],
              ),
              centerTitle: false,
            ),
            body: ListView(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              userData['photoUrl'],
                            ),
                            radius: 40,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    buildStateColumn(postLen, "posts"),
                                    buildStateColumn(followers, "followers"),
                                    buildStateColumn(following, "following"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid ==
                                            widget.uid
                                        ? FollowButton(
                                            text: 'sign out',
                                            backgroundColor:
                                                mobileBackgroundColor,
                                            textColor: primaryColor,
                                            borderColor: Colors.grey,
                                            function: () async {
                                              await AuthMethods().signOut();
                                              Navigator.of(context)
                                                  .pushReplacement(
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      const LoginScreen(),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          )
                                        : isFollowing
                                            ? FollowButton(
                                                text: 'unfollow',
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                                textColor: Colors.black,
                                                borderColor: Colors.grey,
                                                function: () async {
                                                  await FirestoreMethods()
                                                      .followUser(
                                                    FirebaseAuth.instance
                                                        .currentUser!.uid,
                                                    userData['uid'],
                                                  );
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    isFollowing = false;
                                                    followers--;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              )
                                            : FollowButton(
                                                text: 'follow',
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                                borderColor: Colors.blue,
                                                function: () async {
                                                  await FirestoreMethods()
                                                      .followUser(
                                                    FirebaseAuth.instance
                                                        .currentUser!.uid,
                                                    userData['uid'],
                                                  );
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    isFollowing = true;
                                                    followers++;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 15,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          userData['username'],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 1,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          userData['bio'],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(),
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('posts')
                      .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.uid)
                      .get(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    return GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs.length,
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 1.5,
                        childAspectRatio: 1,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot snap =
                            (snapshot.data! as dynamic).docs[index];
                        return Container(
                          child: Image(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              snap['postUrl'],
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  Column buildStateColumn(int num, String label) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          num.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).** Try to simulate what you want to do in your app so we can help!

I've tried to do it based on your code, i've removed firebase related code and replaced `FollowButton` with `ElevatedButton`, just to be able to run it, and it works fine (no errors). Here's the full code (you can copy-paste this to run in a new flutter project, experiment on this and come back if you have a reproducible example of the issue):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const ProfileScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  int postLen = 0;
  int followers = 0;
  int following = 0;
  bool isFollowing = false;
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isFirebaseUserOK = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              title: const Text('username'),
              centerTitle: false,
            ),
            body: ListView(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          const CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"),
                            radius: 40,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    buildStateColumn(postLen, "posts"),
                                    buildStateColumn(followers, "followers"),
                                    buildStateColumn(following, "following"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    isFirebaseUserOK
                                        ? ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("FollowButton"))
                                        : isFollowing
                                            ? ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("FollowButton"))
                                            : ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("FollowButton"))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 15,
                        ),
                        child: const Text('username', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 1,
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(),
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)), //simulate waiting for data
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    return GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 100,
                      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 1.5,
                        childAspectRatio: 1,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                          child: const Image(
                            image: NetworkImage("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  Column buildStateColumn(int num, String label) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          num.toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```